# Installing ufw via ansible but not found in paths

Tags: ansible

I am installing ufw on a fresh Ubutunu 18.04 install. However it doesn't seem to be found in paths. I don't understand the issue

```
- name: test
      apt:
        name: ufw
        state: latest


 - name: "Configure ufw policy"
      ufw:
        policy: "allow"
        direction: "incoming
```

The error

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable ufw in paths: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this seems to have happened because I was running the playbook with the `--check` flag. When I run the playbook 'live' on the server this is no longer an issue.

I'm not sure why this was an issue since the `ufw` package was already installed on the remote server..